# Multiply update MySQL where clause is a View

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update all rows of a table with the same field. How i do this?

```
Create View elencoID as
Select id
from Utenti;

UPDATE Utenti 
SET indirizzo='ggggggg' 
WHERE Id IN (elencoID);
```

Comment: `where id in (select * from elencoid)`. what you have is illegal syntax. but this would be better written as a join, not a subselect.

Comment: Please include more details about what you are expecting. :-)

Comment: Sorry @Shawn, my mistake. I get that's error

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'elencoID' in 'where clause'

Comment: @MarcB can you explain or show me some example,  please?

Comment: No. Please. Just no. I cannot fathom a use case where this would make sense. What are you trying to achieve? And why would you need a view definition to do what you trying to do? No. Just no.  **`UPDATE Utenti SET indirizzo='ggggggg' WHERE Id IS NOT NULL`**.

Comment: @spencer7593 sorry but i forgot the basic sql rules...i doesn't use him for a lot of time. A view it's a test, because with a single query i'm unable to resolved my problem. 
Now i use your code but get that's error: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason for creating a view definition.

If you want to update **ALL** rows in the table to set a specific column to a the same fixed value on every row... again, for **all** rows in the table, just leave off the WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE Utenti
   SET indirizzo='ggggggg'
```

If you feel you need a `WHERE` clause, then you can add a dummy condition that evaluates to true for every row.

```
UPDATE Utenti
   SET indirizzo='ggggggg'
 WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: Thanks.  "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect" it's a MySQL Administrator config...

Comment: Yes it's Workbench, just change `WHERE 1=1` to `WHERE id>0`